# Accessing Class Items from Method

Tags: c#

This seems like an easy question to find the answer to, but I can't find anything quite like this.
I have a class file named Earnings.cs, that will only hold two items (lastYear, thisYear).

The code I have is as follows

```
public void parseEarnData(List<String> earningData)
{
    ... //gets the information

    classAdd(lq1, lq2, lq3, lq4, tq1, tq2, tq3, tq4);
}

public void classAdd(string lqO, string lqT, string lqTh, string lqF, string tqO, string tqT, string tqTh, string tqF)
{
    Earnings lastYear = new Earnings(Convert.ToDecimal(lqO), Convert.ToDecimal(lqT), Convert.ToDecimal(lqTh), Convert.ToDecimal(lqF));
    Earnings thisYear = new Earnings(Convert.ToDecimal(tqO), Convert.ToDecimal(tqT), Convert.ToDecimal(tqTh), Convert.ToDecimal(tqF));
}
```

Then in a method that actually does math, I would like to retrieve lastYear and thisYear. Everything in the class is public, but lastYear and thisYear do not exist in the context of the method for calculations. So my question is how do I access them?

*Class if you think it's important*

```
public class Earnings
{
    public decimal q1 { get; set; }
    public decimal q2{ get; set; }
    public decimal q3{ get; set; }
    public decimal q4{ get; set; }

    public Earnings(decimal q1, decimal q2, decimal q3, decimal q4)
    {
        this.q1 = q1;
        this.q2 = q2;
        this.q3 = q3;
        this.q4 = q4;
    }
}
```

Edit: The variable names just stand for Last Quarter One, Two, etc. and This Quarter One, Two, etc. Sorry for the weird abbreviations.

Edit 2: All the code is written within my Form's class (Form1.cs), and the method that will do the calculations on the data will also be located within the same class. I just want to be able to access the data from the Earnings class in my main code.

Comment: You could return the values from the method.

Comment: Use descriptive variable names. Abbreviations make it difficult or impossible for another programmer (including future-you) to reason about what the code does.

Comment: I will have to access these items all throughout my program, so I really don't want to return them over and over again. I'd rather have them stored in a class for easy access.

Comment: Which class does `classAdd` and `parseEarnData` belong to? What is the relationship between that class and the method that does the actual work?

Comment: I will add an edit for this addition information

Comment: Similar to what Mathias said, it looks like the upper code block should be its own class and lastYear/thisYear should be class fields instead of local method variables.

OP is correct in that it is a "easy question" but it really requires a bit more practice with Object Oriented Programming before this sort of problem will start to "click"

As it is right now its really hard to answer without basically seeing the entire program and opening it for critique. But basically you need to look up the idea of "variable scope" and "class fields vs method variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All the code is written within my Form's class (`Form1.cs`), and the method that will do the calculations on the data will also be located within the same class.

Then you'll probably want to make `lastYear` and `thisYear` part of your form too:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // declare Earnings members
    Earnings lastYear;
    Earnings thisYear;

    // ...

    public void classAdd(string lqO, string lqT, string lqTh, string lqF, string tqO, string tqT, string tqTh, string tqF)
    {
        // assign values to declared instance members
        lastYear = new Earnings(Convert.ToDecimal(lqO), Convert.ToDecimal(lqT), Convert.ToDecimal(lqTh), Convert.ToDecimal(lqF));
        thisYear = new Earnings(Convert.ToDecimal(tqO), Convert.ToDecimal(tqT), Convert.ToDecimal(tqTh), Convert.ToDecimal(tqF));
    }

    public void doActualWork()
    {
        // now you can access lastYear and thisYear in this scope too
    }
}
```

It's not important which source code file contains the definition for `Earnings` - it's just a blueprint we can use elsewhere :-)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize I had to declare the members before assigning values. I assumed with classes it was an all-in-one thing.

Comment: @boo Variables declared in a method are called local variables. Usually (except in iterator methods and for captured variables etc.) these variables exist only during one method call and are only accessible within this method. If you need to keep information stored between method calls and accessible by several methods, you must declare them on the class level. Such variables are also called fields. Their lifetime extends to the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes For some reason I was thinking that class objects were exempt from that when in a public method. I should've realized this because I've been working in VB.NET and the exact same thing applies to structures, so there's really no real reason for classes to be a special exception to the scope of things. I've just had a long day and switching from language to language really throws me off of my groove.

Comment: There is no fundamental difference on this subject between VB and C# and between structs and classes. The difference lies in the different variables scopes and lifetimes between fields and local variables. An exception are Static local variables in VB. These don't exist in C#.